# Localhost on Android using Slim Framework (PHP) and Mac OS X

Tags: android, networking, localhost

I've followed other StackOverflow postings on how to get localhost working which I have done, but when I run Slim Framework using port 8080 on localhost, it keeps saying "The site can't be reached" when I try to put `http://localhost:8080/someroute` in the Chrome browser on Android. `http://localhost:80` works, but not `http://localhost:8080`

I have
`127.0.0.1   ipv4 address with/without port 8080` already in /etc/hosts on my computer (mac os x)

Is there something I'm missing? Note, I am not using emulator, but real device.

Comment: Do you actually have a webserver running on port 8080?

Comment: @MikaTuupola I have slim framework running on port 8080 yes. I have XAMPP running with Apache that I use in tandem with slim framework. I can connect to XAMPP through port 80 of course, but slim framework nope.

Comment: @MikaTuupola I use the command `php -S localhost:8080` to start Slim Framework on Mac OS X. I can never connect to localhost:8080 on Android though and am only able to do localhost:80. I can use Slim Framework on my computer though fine without problems.

Comment: External device cannot connect to localhost. You can connect to localhost only from the same device you started the server in. Bind the webserver to a public ip address and connect using that ip address.

Comment: @MikaTuupola Not necessarily. I told you earlier I was able to access localhost XAMPP earlier on Android when I started XAMPP localhost on my computer. I changed the /etc/hosts file to contain `127.0.0.1   ipv4 address` but I just can't access stuff on port 8080

Comment: @John61590 did you manage to get it work.